# ErrorException Attempt to modify property 'parent' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to create parent child tree in laravel 7 but gets the error

*ErrorException Attempt to modify property 'parent' of non-object* 
on this line

```
 $index ->parent['children']->[] = &$row;
```

Here is  original php code which works fine

```
$userinfo = array();
    foreach ($sql as $row_user ) {
      $rows[] = $row_user ;
      $index = array();
    }

 // build the tree
foreach($index as $id => &$row)
{
  if ($id === 0) continue;
  $parent = $row['parent'];
  $index [$parent]['children'][] = &$row;
}
unset($row);
```

I cannot set the $index value. Please advise.
The Index value is for storing the parent/children sort order value.

Basically it is passing value by reference  or copy from reference;

Comment: what actually the `$index` is initialized to?

Comment: $index = array();

Comment: what you want to do with `$index` please explain you query in detail.

Comment: The Index value is for storing the parent/children sort order value.